# HTML5 date input on Android 4.4 browser / webview

Tags: android, html, webview, android-4.4-kitkat

I've noticed an issue where the native datepicker that pops up when tapping a `<input type="date" />` field on the Android 4.4 (KitKat) browser or webview shows the wrong date. See the following example:

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">
  <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form>
    <input type="date" value="2014-10-26" />
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Renders just fine (in my local format of DD/MM/YYYY automatically):

[image: ok]

But.. when you tap the field to open the datepicker it defaults to today's date!

[image: notok]

Anyone else experienced this issue? Maybe my `value` attribute isn't in the correct format? (I've tried others such as DD/MM/YYYY, but those render with a blank input field)

Comment: Hi James, This looks working fine on Android kitkat 4.4.2. I tried on chrome & mozilla browsers. Which subversion of kitkat are you using? And browser too?

Comment: I'm using `4.4.2` too, and the stock browser ("Browser"). It's an emulator, don't have a real KitKat device right now but will try it out on one when I can...

Comment: android input format is: MM/DD/YYYY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems this is a specific issue in WebViews for Android 4.4.2. There's an issue opened for this bug:

[In WebView input type time and date (Nexus 7)](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=64678)

I'm dealing with the same issue, so I hope they solve it.

I'll let you know if I can find any workaround.

Thanks!

Comment: They'll solve it by releasing a new version of Android.  This bug will always remain in 4.4.2!